# How to access the camera from my Windows Phone 8 app (XAML and C#) and save the taken picture in a determined folder?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, save, directory

I want the Windows Phone 8 app that I am building at this moment to access the camera for taking a photo when a concrete button on the screen is pressed and then save the image that has been taken into a determined folfer (a folder created into the Windows Phone project by me, not the Windows Phone default image gallery).

Could you help me accesing the camera, taking the picture and saving it into the folder created by me, please? I am using XAML and C#.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend PhotoCamera class if capture is to be processed on a button in the app

```
 PhotoCamera myCamera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
 //viewfinderBrush is a videobrush object declared in xaml
 viewfinderBrush.SetSource(myCamera);
 myCamera.Initialized += myCamera_Initialized;
 myCamera.CaptureCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(camera_CaptureCompleted);
 myCamera.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(camera_CaptureImageAvailable);
```

//Events

```
   void myCamera_Initialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Succeeded)
            {

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem occured in camera initialization.");
        }
    }

 void camera_CaptureCompleted(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Captured image is not available, please try again.");
            }
        }

void camera_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Captured image is not available, please try again.   " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

And there is one more alternative called **CameraCaptureTask**

```
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;
cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
cameraCaptureTask.Show();

void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
        //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        //myImage.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for PhotoCamera class

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for CameraCaptureTask

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple code demonstration here showing your to put the camera API to use for Windows Phone8 apps.

```
 private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

 if ((PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true) ||
     (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true))  {
     // Initialize the default camera.
     _photoCamera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera();

     //Event is fired when the PhotoCamera object has been initialized
     _photoCamera.Initialized += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(OnPhotoCameraInitialized);

      //Set the VideoBrush source to the camera
      viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);
  }
  else {
      // The camera is not supported on the device.
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()  {
      // Write message.
          txtDebug.Text = "A Camera is not available on this device.";
      });

  }

}

private void OnPhotoCameraInitialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e) {
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Width);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Height);
}
```

Dont forget to add this line in WMAppManifent.xml file.

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
```

you can read here ,

[Using Cameras in Your Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx)