# Activate the back camera on WP8 Device

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, camera

I'm trying to do something very simple: implement a program that activates the back camera of my WP8 device. Could anyone help me do that?

Comment: Activate in the sense, you wanted to open the `Camera` app programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If so you could try using the [PhotoCamera](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.photocamera%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class in order to capture images. I'm not pretty sure whether you'll be able to open the native `Camera` app of the device.

References:

- [How to access the camera from my Windows Phone 8 app (XAML and C#) and save the taken picture in a determined folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505769/)
- [Sample from MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Camera-Sample-52dae359)
- [Minimal Camera app in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Minimal_Camera_app_in_Windows_Phone)

Comment: Hey there, it helped me to something, but it isn't enough.My program should show up the camera when I slide a PivotPage. You got something?

Comment: Did you try show up the camera, within your `Pivot` selection changed event?